# Upgrade to 22.04 LTS - won't boot from Grub - root boot not found

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

Over the weekend I upgraded my dual boot ACER A314 laptop from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, and then 22.04 LTS. The 22.04 LTS installation seemed to work, but on first reboot, failed.

The error messages from attempted recovery mode boot are

- 'Cannot open root device....append or correct "root=" boot option....Kernel panic - unable to mount root fs on unknown block (0,0)'

So far I have, using a Live USB of 22.04:

- created a chroot environment
- updated/regenerated initramfs using 'update-initramfs -u all' for the two kernels that dpkg sees
- installed grub with target x86_efi, followed by install recheck
- updated grub.

All the above gave me a working grub with Ubuntu, Windows and UEFI entries.  But the problem persists.

I have also subsequently run the Boot-repair program in basic mode from Live CD - problem not solved.

Both the Ubuntu and EFI partitions have 50% free space.
The kernels that dpkg sees are 5.4 versions - I would have expected 5.15 or higher - don't know about this.

How to proceed/fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Acer's require "trust" on UEFI boot entry. Since grub also updated, did it create a new UEFI boot entry that now needs trust setting in UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu).  Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Comment: I have been into the machine UEFI settings (F2) and set the three efi files for ubuntu to permitted yes. Reboot, and problem persists. 
However, I have seen in the recovery boot messages the following: 'Revoking X.509 certificate: UEFI:dbx.; blacklist: Revoked X.509 cert 'Acer database forbidden''
Are there other possible reasons this error message?

Comment: Looking into the X509 message - it seems this relates to secure boot, which I am not doing.

Comment: I thought to set trust you had to turn UEFI Secure Boot on. But then may want to turn it back off. Also UEFI updates may reset UEFI to defaults which may turn it back on.

Comment: Yes, to access enablement of the efi files you toggle secure boot on.  Then you enable the files. Toggle secure boot off again, save and exit.  Checked again this morning to see it was done correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going down and eliminating many rabbit holes, the clue was in the kernel versions.

I ran Boot-repair, with the "purge kernel" selection checked, within advanced options - grub.

This deleted the old 5.4 kernels and installed a 5.15 kernel.

At the same time, I purged and recreated grub, using the tool option.

Finally, a working Ubuntu 22.04.